# Is Firebird 2.1 efficient to store a massive number of rows in some DB's table?

Tags: database, database-design, firebird, firebird2.1

My application keeps receiving a really small event that it needs to store and I was thinking which is the best way to handle it. The table for this event would be something like this:

```
EVENT
id
timestamp
some_data (integer)
fk_to_some_holder_table
```

If I keep storing each event as a row, will there be some disadvantage against an implementation with some kind of blob compression/treatment? Or am I going too far here?

I'm using Firebird 2.1. If needed, I could upgrade to Firebird 2.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Databases are designed to store large amounts of data, and the definition you've provided definitely would not require any use of blobs or compression, and using either of them needlessly would add totally unnecessary overhead. Can you clarify exactly what you're asking?

Comment: You are doing it the correct way. Database systems are designed exactly for storing massive amounts of rows. Don't worry about compression, you will be wasting your time. And don't under any circumstances make the mistake of trying to use blobs!

Comment: You are right. My question is specific about the Firebird 2.1 implementation. I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: When I first took over the database at my current job, it was originally setup with some fields as BLOBS, it was ridiculous what you had to do just to echo the blob (in php) so I switched them all to just normal rows, no difference that anyone has noticed, plus some tables in our db have 600,000 + rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure you're better off with "traditional row based record":

- you want to query the records, right? Quering BLOBs is hard and slow;
- since your record size is so small you wouldn't be able to compress them, with most compression algorithms the result would probably be bigger than the separate fields require;

According to the "[What are the technical limits of Firebird?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq61/)" article maximum size of one table is 32TB or 16G rows.

I don't think there is any difference between 2.1 and 2.5 in this specific case, but I'd use 2.5 because of other/general improvements.

Comment: But if I get a lot of small records, I can put them in a BLOB and compress that BLOB. I'll make some tests and post the results here.

Comment: Well, it looks like you just enjoy the additional works it brings <g> Make some calculations with the numbers in my answer - does it make sense to worry about the space, do you get so many records that there is danger to run into the limits? Assuming that `id` and `fk_to_some_holder_table` are 64 bit integers your record is 224 bits or 28 bytes. So 32TB / 28 = 1.1T rows, ie the row limit is more important. However, if you get 1 row per second then 16G rows is good for 16G / 86400 = 185185 days or about 500 years.

Comment: @haole AFAIK, Firebird uses RLE compression internally when storing data. It might be as efficient as some doing it externally, it's good to note that some compression is already done.

Answer (score 0):

storing as a row makes much better sense than blobs, for the reasons already mentioned

I'd stick with 2.1 for now, 2.5 has too many bugs for my liking